# Identical objects are not equal and have different identityHashCode outputs when using AsyncSnapshot

Tags: dart

I have 2 objects which are identical (because I simply added it to a set and pass it back in a Stream (actually **BehaviorSubject** but this extends Stream and is not too relevant for this issue).

I don't know **why they are not equal**, when their contents are equal. My check fails: `a == b` is `false`, and when a is a set, `{a}.contains(b)` is `false`. The only thing I could think of is I am using AsyncSnapshot to listen to these values:

```dart
  Widget shouldBeTrue(AsyncSnapshot<MyData> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      bool incorrectResult = snapshot.data!.contains(launchMission);
      return incorrectResult // This is False, but should be true 
    }
  }
```

After running `identityHashCode` on them, they are different too, giving different numbers as outputs.

---

The debugger output showing the 2 different objects, they have the same contents:[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly you have two separate objects instead of two references to the same object. If you didn't implement `operator ==`, it doesn't matter if they have the same contents; the default `==` implementation checks only object identity.

Comment: Oh, I thought there was implicit equals operator, like a kotlin data class. Thanks, I will have to implement that.

Comment: See the "Equatable" mixin to get about 80% of what you need for first-layer equality.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended** solution, suggested by Randal Schwartz:

- Use [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable). The docs actually explains the problem and solution. To summarize, by default `==` only compares if 2 objects are the same instance, not if they contain the same data (e.g. properties/ state).

---

My initial solution before using [EquatableMixin](https://pub.dev/documentation/equatable/latest/equatable/EquatableMixin-mixin.html) from the equatable package.

Thanks to jamesdlin, I realized my code was insufficient. To fix, I overrode both [operator ==](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.1/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) and [get hashCode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html):

```dart
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

class LaunchMission { 
  ...
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return (other is LaunchMission)
      && flightNumber == other.flightNumber;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(flightNumber, name);
}
```

The hashCode property override was needed. Without it, `set.contains` would not return `true`.

> If operator == is overridden to use the object state instead, the hash code must also be changed to represent that state, **otherwise the object cannot be used in hash based data structures like the default Set and Map implementations**.